# Are nested helpers (subexpressions) supported in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

I would use this: http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions

`{{outer-helper (inner-helper 'abc') 'def'}}`

But meteor give me an error...there is some solution or workaround for use nested helpers?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible with version 1.2

```
<p>
    Together we have
    {{pluralize (add myWidgetCount yourWidgetCount), "widget"}}
</p>
```

https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI#dbfACAYxaJX

Answer (score 2):

Nested Helper: If there is a positional argument followed by other (positional or keyword arguments), the first argument is called on the others using the normal helper argument calling convention.

Passing helperB to helperA

```
{{helperA helperB}}
```

Passing 'helperB with argument x' to helperA

```
{{helperA helperB x}}
```

Passing 'helperB with argument x=false' to helperA

```
{{helperA helperB x=false}}
```

**Spacebars inclusion and block arguments**

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#inclusion-and-block-arguments

Comment: And if I want pass a param to helprA and one to helperB (see my example above)

Comment: then block helper syntax would more explicit and maintainable

`{{#outer-helper def}}
  {{inner-helper abc}}
{{/outer-helper}}`

Comment: another example `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">
              {{#spinnerIf processing}}{{#if addMode}}Add{{else}}Edit{{/if}}{{/spinnerIf}}
          </button>` does that answer your question?

Comment: My question is really old ...I don't remember well. Btw, you use a block helper not a simple helper for allow nested call. And this is not the same... Eg I can pass only one param to a block helper.

Comment: For what I have understand this ( http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) is impossible with meteor

Comment: that is correct, but you can nest helpers using different syntax as I demonstrated. I believe this solves your problem as you have asked for a workaround in your question, right? It is not impossible to nest helpers, you're just not able to do it using that same mustache syntax.

Comment: Right :) ...but the problems was that my outer-helper already existed and I would like reuse it  with nested behaviour

Comment: However +1 for you :)

Comment: It seems there is no answer you would accept as correct. If feels a bit unfair if you won't accept an honest solution because you are unwilling to refactor any code. Can you modify your question to include a bit of context? what is the nature of the arguments your outer-helper is expecting? You could always write another helper which is a wrapper for your original outer-helper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71996/discussion-between-max-hodges-and-elbowz).

Answer (score 0):

i think this part of the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_registerhelper, and this part http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers should answer your question.

Also, meteors template language is called *spacebars*, although inspired by **handlebars**, it has some differnces, more to read here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md

This will give us:

```
// template
<template name="_maybeDiv_wrapInDiv">
  <div>
    {{> UI.contentBlock}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="_maybeDiv_noop">
  {{> UI.contentBlock}}
</template>

// client code
UI.registerHelper('maybeDiv', function () {
  var isBlock = this.valueOf();

  if (isBlock)
    return Template._maybeDiv_wrapInDiv;
  else
    return Template._maybeDiv_noop;
});
```

and you can use it like

```
{{#maybeDiv true}}
  contents
{{/maybeDiv}}
```

Comment: Excuse Me, but i don't understand where is the answer to my question...Is possible or no, do nested helper call, as in Handlebar? and how?

Comment: mhhh...and where is Nested Helper (Subexpression) like {{outer-helper (inner-helper 'abc') 'def'}} ?

Comment: If this answers the question it does a terrible job explaining it. I see nothing about nested helpers in there. I would downvote this if I could.

Comment: `{{#maybeDiv true}}
  contents
{{/maybeDiv}}` replace contents with another helper and you have nested helpers.

Comment: I dont get it. Seems to be hackish.